# How to replace 'latest' in the output lambda function url? How could I make my own resource?

Tags: node.js, rest, amazon-web-services, lambda, claudiajs

I am new to `AWS Lambda`.

As given in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html#api-gateway-proxy-integration-lambda-function-nodejs), I deployed the following sample on `AWS Lambda` using Claudia:

```
'use strict';
console.log('Loading hello world function');

exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
    var name = "World";
    var responseCode = 200;
    console.log("request: " + JSON.stringify(event));
    if (event.queryStringParameters !== null && event.queryStringParameters !== undefined) {
        if (event.queryStringParameters.name !== undefined && event.queryStringParameters.name !== null && event.queryStringParameters.name !== "") {
            console.log("Received name: " + event.queryStringParameters.name);
            name = event.queryStringParameters.name;
        }

        if (event.queryStringParameters.httpStatus !== undefined && event.queryStringParameters.httpStatus !== null && event.queryStringParameters.httpStatus !== "") {
            console.log("Received http status: " + event.queryStringParameters.httpStatus);
            responseCode = event.queryStringParameters.httpStatus;
        }
    }

    var responseBody = {
        message: "Hello " + name + "!",
        input: event
    };
    var response = {
        statusCode: responseCode,
        headers: {
            "x-custom-header": "my custom header value"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(responseBody)
    };
    console.log("response: " + JSON.stringify(response))
    callback(null, response);
};
```

The command I used to deploy using `Claudia` is:

```
claudia create --region us-east-1 --deploy-proxy-api --handler main.handler
```

It created a URL that looks like:
`https://40barfooxpyj.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/latest`

Why do I get the string `latest` in the URL? How could I make the URL look like:
`https://40barfooxpyj.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/api/jobs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you'll want to use [Claudia API Builder](http://ivanjov.com/building-serverless-api-with-claudia-api-builder/)

In your case, something along the lines of:

```
api.get('jobs', function(request) {
    return "Hello " + request.queryString.name + "!";
});
```

You'll also want to set --version in your create command, for example:

```
claudia create --region us-east-1 --deploy-proxy-api --handler main.handler --version api
```

Comment: --version api will change "latest" to "api", api.get('jobs', ... creates a final endpoint of /api/jobs

Comment: Okay. What If I need `api/jobs` at the end?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here... Following my answer, your endpoint will be:  `https://40barfooxpyj.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/api/jobs`

or: `https://40barfooxpyj.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/api/jobs?name=bob`

Comment: Okay! How should I define a proxy resource? Also, I do not want to use claudia api builder.  What should be the approach then to parse the HTTP requests?

Comment: [https://claudiajs.com/tutorials/deploying-proxy-api.html](https://claudiajs.com/tutorials/deploying-proxy-api.html)

API builder is pretty much the standard in handling HTTP requests within claudia..  The answer to how to do that otherwise is outside of the scope of the initial question.